# HTTP Post multiple objects using json in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I have a Rails API. I want to make http request to server with multiple objects. The data is something like that:

```
[
    {
        "flowmeter_id":9,
        "volume_value":666
    },
    {
        "flowmeter_id":10,
        "volume_value":777
    },
    {  
        "flowmeter_id":11,
        "volume_value":888
    }
]
```

I need to create action, but I have no idea how to do that. How the controller's action should work?

Comment: I noticed, that user_id is the same in the object, maybe it's an association for a particular user, so you can send an update request to the user? Just some thoughts...

Comment: Never mind that user. I changed the json.